# JavaFX NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error and how to solve it? Also try to keep it simple. I'm new to coding. (Also i know the answer to the question exists, but i don't know how to implement it to my code)

It gives NullPointerException error when rows are deleted. Also when the blocks move down, the blocks are still counted as 0 so new blocks go through them. (i guess its only the top row, other rows are working as intended) But the actual error is more important: (but i'd be happy if you help to solve this too)

```
package application;

import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Tetris extends Application {
  public static final int MOVE_AMOUNT = 25;
  public static final int SIZE = 25;
  public static int XLIMIT = SIZE * 10;
  public static int YLIMIT = SIZE * 24;
  public static int[][] GRID = new int[XLIMIT/SIZE][YLIMIT/SIZE];
  private static Pane group = new Pane();
  private static Shape object;
  private static Scene scene = new Scene(group, XLIMIT, YLIMIT);

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    for(int[] a: GRID){
        Arrays.fill(a, 0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= XLIMIT; i+= SIZE){
        Line a = new Line(i, 0, i, YLIMIT);
        group.getChildren().add(a);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= YLIMIT; i+= SIZE){
        Line a = new Line(0, i, XLIMIT, i);
        group.getChildren().add(a);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= YLIMIT; i+= SIZE){
        Text a = new Text("" + i);
        a.setY(i);
        group.getChildren().add(a);
    }
    for(int i = SIZE; i < XLIMIT; i+= SIZE){
        Text a = new Text("" + i);
        a.setY(10);
        a.setX(i);
        group.getChildren().add(a);
    }
    Shape a = TetrisHolder.createRect();
    group.getChildren().addAll(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d);
    moveOnKeyPress(scene, a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d);
    object = a;
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    Timer myTimer=new Timer();
    TimerTask task =new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                  CheckDown(object);
              }
          });
        }
      };
      myTimer.schedule(task,0,300);

    }

  private void moveOnKeyPress(Scene scene, Rectangle rect, Rectangle rect2, Rectangle rect3, Rectangle rect4) {
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        Shape shape = new Shape(rect, rect2, rect3, rect4);
        switch (event.getCode()) {
          case RIGHT: 
              TetrisHolder.CheckRight(shape);
              break;
          case DOWN:  
              CheckDown(shape);
              break;
          case LEFT:  
              TetrisHolder.CheckLeft(shape);
              break;
          case UP:
              //TetrisHolder.CheckTurn(shape);
              break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private void CheckTurn(Shape shape){

  }

  private void DeleteRows(Pane pane){
      ArrayList<Node> rects = new ArrayList<Node>();
      ArrayList<Integer> lines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int full = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < GRID[0].length; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < GRID.length; j++){
              if(GRID[j][i] == 1)
                  full++;
          }
          if(full == GRID.length)
              lines.add(i/*+lines.size()*/);
          full = 0;
      }
      for(Node node: pane.getChildren()) {
           if(node instanceof Rectangle) {
                rects.add(node);
            }
        }
      if(lines.size() > 0)
          do{
              for(Node node: rects){
                  Rectangle a = (Rectangle)node;
                  if(a.getY() == lines.get(0)*SIZE){
                      GRID[(int)a.getX()/SIZE][(int)a.getY()/SIZE] = 0;
                      pane.getChildren().remove(node);
                  }
                  if(a.getY() < lines.get(0)*SIZE){
                      GRID[(int)a.getX()/SIZE][(int)a.getY()/SIZE] = 0;
                      a.setY(a.getY() + SIZE);
                      GRID[(int)a.getX()/SIZE][(int)a.getY()/SIZE] = 1;
                  }
              }
              lines.remove(0);
              rects.clear();
              for(Node node: pane.getChildren()) {
                   if(node instanceof Rectangle) {
                        rects.add(node);
                    }
                }
          } while(lines.size() > 0);
  }

  private void CheckDown(Shape shape){
      if((shape.c.getY() == YLIMIT - SIZE) || checkA(shape) || checkB(shape) || checkC(shape) || checkD(shape)){
          GRID[(int)shape.a.getX()/SIZE][(int)shape.a.getY()/SIZE] = 1;
          GRID[(int)shape.b.getX()/SIZE][(int)shape.b.getY()/SIZE] = 1;
          GRID[(int)shape.c.getX()/SIZE][(int)shape.c.getY()/SIZE] = 1;
          GRID[(int)shape.d.getX()/SIZE][(int)shape.d.getY()/SIZE] = 1;
          DeleteRows(group);
          Shape a = TetrisHolder.createRect();
          object = a;
          group.getChildren().addAll(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d);
          moveOnKeyPress(shape.a.getScene(), a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d);
          }
      if(shape.c.getY() + MOVE_AMOUNT < YLIMIT){
          int checka = GRID[(int)shape.a.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.a.getY()/SIZE) + 1];
          int checkb = GRID[(int)shape.b.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.b.getY()/SIZE) + 1];
          int checkc = GRID[(int)shape.c.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.c.getY()/SIZE) + 1];
          int checkd = GRID[(int)shape.d.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.d.getY()/SIZE) + 1];
          if(checka == 0 && checka == checkb && checkb == checkc && checkc == checkd){
              shape.a.setY(shape.a.getY() + MOVE_AMOUNT);
              shape.b.setY(shape.b.getY() + MOVE_AMOUNT);
              shape.c.setY(shape.c.getY() + MOVE_AMOUNT);
              shape.d.setY(shape.d.getY() + MOVE_AMOUNT);
              }
          }
      }

  private boolean checkA(Shape shape){
      return (GRID[(int)shape.a.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.a.getY()/SIZE) + 1] == 1);
  }
  private boolean checkB(Shape shape){
      return (GRID[(int)shape.b.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.b.getY()/SIZE) + 1] == 1);
  }
  private boolean checkC(Shape shape){
      return (GRID[(int)shape.c.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.c.getY()/SIZE) + 1] == 1);
  }
  private boolean checkD(Shape shape){
      return (GRID[(int)shape.d.getX()/SIZE][((int)shape.d.getY()/SIZE) + 1] == 1);
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.Tetris.moveOnKeyPress(Tetris.java:70)
at application.Tetris.CheckDown(Tetris.java:147)
at application.Tetris.access$1(Tetris.java:137)
at application.Tetris$1$1.run(Tetris.java:60)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Comment: `Shape a = TetrisHolder.createRect();` either this call returns a `null`shape object, or a shape with at least a requiered field is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you getting the scene from a shape if you still have a reference to a static scene at the top?

I'd say try switching the following out at line 70:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
```

to this:

```
this.scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a shape which is null.

In your case, if you look at line 70, you are trying to perform `scene.setOnKeyPressed`, but scene is null.

You are calling in 2 places the `moveOnKeyPress` method. 
Where your problem is calling this method at line 147, where you do `shape.a.getScene()`. That call to `getScene()` is null.

Furthermore, if you look where you call `CheckDown`, you have them in 2 places, but your problematic call is at line 60.

Not sure what you do at line 48 (`Shape a = TetrisHolder.createRect();`), but I suspect there might be something wrong with setting up the `scene`

What I did here is translate your stacktrace:

```
at application.Tetris.moveOnKeyPress(Tetris.java:70)
at application.Tetris.CheckDown(Tetris.java:147)
at application.Tetris.access$1(Tetris.java:137)
at application.Tetris$1$1.run(Tetris.java:60)
```

Comment: @Ellisan he does, but he never uses it on the object that he wants to pass. If you look at `Shape a = TetrisHolder.createRect();`, he then passes the reference to `object` and sets the scene created above to `stage`, not to the `Shape`, and then he does a call to `shape.a.getScene()`. Honestly, the code is pretty confusing, I dragged the code in my IDE to understand what is he trying to achieve. I might be wrong, so let me know

Comment: Yes you are correct, i saw that later aswell. Im also slightly confused what he is trying to do soince he still has a static reference to `scene` up top

Comment: That makes sense. Also after deleting, the rows goes so wrong. (the grid) Do you guys know how to solve that?